# C++: anything wrong with the following code?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I got the the following code:

```
T *p = new T[10];
delete p;
```

It should be delete [] p, I think. I tried it on T=int type, no error. Then I created a simple class, exception. Any clear explanation?

```
T *p = 0;
delete p;
```

What's wrong with them? [I looked it up, it seems that although delete p will lead to error, but program resume because compiler thinks p==0 in the first place, so this error does not matter.]

Answer (score 5):

Yes,
You should call  `delete [] p;`

> **Any clear explanation?**

It is undefined behavior to:

- Call `delete` if allocation was through `new []`
- Call `delete` on non dynamically allocated pointer.

Note that **Undefined Behavior** means that anything can happen, it does not mandate a crash. It simply means your program can show any behavior(including working as expected).

It is perfectly valid to call `delete` on a `NULL` pointer. The standard allows that. The `delete` operator internally takes core of that, the caller does not have to bother about the `NULL` check.

---

**References:**

**C++03 standard §3.7.4.2-3:**

> *If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the behavior is undefined. The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect. Otherwise, the value supplied
>   to operator `delete(void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator `new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_-t&)` in the standard library, and the value supplied to operator `delete[](void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](std::size_t)` or
>   `operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library.*

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate an array of objects with `new[]`, you must delete it with `delete[]`. Failing to do so results in **Undefined Behavior**.

The main behavioral difference between `delete` and `delete[]` is that the latter, apart from deallocating the memory, also invokes the destructor of each object in the array.

Considering your second point:

```
T *p = 0;
delete p;
```

This will not cause an error, but rather do nothing, because that's the expected behavior of `delete` when the pointer is null.

Comment: Technically innacurate. Calling `delete` instead of `delete[]` is UB.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: agree, i will edit it. however, i did not mean to say you can call `delete` instead of `delete[]`. rather, i wanted to point out what is the difference in behavior between the two. but yes, you have a point.